# Problems with applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

My code for application will Enter Foreground is given below. I am working on the iOS simulator. What I am trying in my code is, when a player clicks home button while game is going on and returns back to the game after sometime, I want the game to be in pause state. Although my code pauses the game, but it does not pause it immediately. That is, when I go to my game again, there is 1 second of movement before everything pauses.

```
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application 
{ [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didEnterForeground" object:self];
}

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                        selector: @selector(handleEnterFg)
                                                 name: @"didEnterForeground"
                                               object: nil];



-(void) handleEnterFg
{

if (gameIsOver== NO)


{
    [myTimer pause];

    gamePause = YES;
    self.scene.view.paused = YES;


}


}



 -(void) handleEnterBg 
{ 
if (gameIsOver== NO)
 { 
[bgPlayer pause]; 
[self childNodeWithName:@"pauseButton"].zPosition = -10; 
[self childNodeWithName:@"playButton"].zPosition = 160; 
}
 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pause the game when you receive `applicationWillEnterBackground` if you want to pause it immediately.

Comment: Actually my Will Enter Background has this. I have 2 buttons: play and pause, and I want to change the zPositions depending on whether the game is paused or not.  I can't put self.scene.view.paused = YES in this block, because then the positions of my nodes(play and pause) do not change. What should I do? 

-(void) handleEnterBg

{
    

    
    if (gameIsOver== NO)
        
    
    {
     
     [bgPlayer pause];
    [self childNodeWithName:@"pauseButton"].zPosition = -10;
    [self childNodeWithName:@"playButton"].zPosition = 160;




    }
     
   

    }